# WordPress Publish Button Ghosts on Long Posts

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a blogging problem I can't seem to resolve.

Twice a week I have posts that are longer than the rest of the week. The posts are lists of coupons with image and link for each one. When I get it all ready to post, I go to click on the green publish button and it just sits there as if I haven't clicked on anything so this won't post. I have gotten them to post a few times if I let it just sit there for an hour or two but the past few days it won't do it even then.

While it sits there I can open another wp-admin browser window and work in a new post and even if it's short, it won't post while the long one is still open in another window. The short one will accept the click on the green publish button, but will give me a white page and an error message that says no data. Something about the server sending no data.

If I close the window with the long unpublished post and wait quite a while the short one will post ok. Often times after publishing a post it will give me the 500 error code but every time I check my blog it's posted so I've gotten used to disregarding the 500 notice because that tells me my post went through.

I'm self -taught so I'm still pretty green. I'm running the up to date version of WordPress, and the theme is Mantra. My active theme is my Mantra Child theme I put together after getting tired of my customizations in Mantra being lost when the theme upgraded. I taught myself how to do the child theme. The problem was still happening before I added the child theme anyway though.

I had been having trouble with my blog loading way way too slowly so I disabled all my plug-ins and activated them one by one and found the culprit to be Jetpack,so Jetpack is still among my installed plugins but I have it deactivated.

My blog is CalvaryCouponers.com

Any assistance is very much appreciated! Thank you in advance :)

Helen

Comment: Sorry for typos...autocorrect is not my friend!

Answer (score 0):

I heard Jetpack can cause issues with publish button not working, and it often happens without it. The wordpress automatically saves a draft every once in a while, and sometimes it stucks. When it does that it adds `disabled` class on the publish button, so you cannot click on it. One workaround is to inspect it, find the `disabled` class, and you can remove it, and publish it.

A small hack I found online is to put this in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'fix_autosave' );

function fix_autosave() { ?>
<a href="javascript:;"
   style="float:right;margin:10px;"
   onclick="jQuery('#submitpost input').removeClass('disabled');return false;">unlock</a>
<?php
}
```

This adds a 'unlock' link that will, on click, remove that class from the post box so you should be able to publish your post.

This is however a hack, and there should be some reason behind this, so you should try to see what could be causing this, and use this as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Thank you for the hack! I will try that after I've gotten some sleep :)   Otherwise I just do a search for the word "disabled" in the functions.php file and remove it?  (told you I'm self taught, sorry...).  Or is there more characters along with "disabled" I need to remove with it?    Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: No, the `disabled` class is added in the html in the backend. When you inspect the button on the wordpress backend (right click and Inspect), you can see the disabled class there, not in the `functions.php`.

Comment: I added the hack to the functions.php (at the very end) and I got a white screen with this:  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/content/09/11415909/html/wp-content/themes/mantrachild/functions.php on line 1"  in it.  I had to reupload my backup files via ftp to get my blog back.  So I inspected the backend for the disabled class and it's not there.  So I decided to add a new file to my child theme called functions.php and add the hack code there and the same thing happened so I deleted the new file and now I'm back to where I was when I posted this call for help.

Comment: This is odd, plus if you've added the code at the end of the `functions.php` file, the error would have been there, at that line, not at line 1. Do you have any javascript errors in your console while in backend?

Comment: I do show two errors when checking the backend and I don't know what to do for those either:  http://ws.amazon.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=US&ID=V2…%2F8009%2F65e1edaf-0dad-4905-b5b3-ac7fa7cae167&Operation=GetScriptTemplate Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
calvarycouponers.com/:1264 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Comment: I mean I'm assuming I can change the amazon widget on the side bar, but it shows two errors and it only describes the one as being the amazon widget

Comment: Here's the image  http://calvarycouponers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/backend-errors.jpg

Comment: four more just showed up;  http://calvarycouponers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/backend-errors-March-17-early-am.jpg

Comment: When I inspect you site, you have 32 errors. You should hire someone who'll fix all these problems :\